# django template reverse url，how to pass a jquery variable

Tags: jquery, django, url

url.py

```
url(r'^admin/index/$', 'forum.admin.index',name='admin_index'),
```

template:

```
<li class="link" value="admin_index">link</li>
<div id="main"></div>
.......
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link").click(function () {
        var link_value= $(this).attr("value");
        var addr = {% url link_value %}    {# here is the error #}
        $("#main").load(addr,function(){
            $("#main").fadeIn(100);
        })
})
```

error: from django 1.5, url view name should have a quote.

how can i pass a jquery variable to django template url reverse

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.  But you can to set the value of the `<li>` and use it directly in the `click()` function:

```
<li class="link" value="{% url 'admin_index' %}">link</li>
<div id="main"></div>
.......
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link").click(function () {
        var addr = $(this).attr("value");
        $("#main").load(addr,function(){
            $("#main").fadeIn(100);
        })
})
```

Comment: but the actual url is 'admin/index' , I want get the actual url reversed with {%url ...%}.
As your code , I must add a click function for each link

Comment: or I add the <li value    with actual url ,  but it is not dry code

Comment: You haven't any other sane option.  You can't use template tags/filters from JS.

Answer (score 0):

so stupid I am!

```
<li class="link" value="{%url 'admin_index' %}">link</li>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link").click(function () {
        $("#main").load($(this).attr("value"),function(){
            $("#main").fadeIn(100);
        })
})
```